# What to do when there is an issue with inserting images in pygame?

Tags: python

When I was trying to insert an image in `pygame`, I heard people say *your images have to be in the same directory as pygame* and I'm not sure what that means. I was hoping someone could help me, Thank You.

I know all the commands and how to insert an `image` but it gives me an error because the image is *not in the same directory*

My wish is to have my image as a background in my screen.

Comment: You have a python file that you're running to start the game, right? Like `game.py` or something. Your images have to be in the same directory as that (e.g., if you refer to `background.png` in `game.py`, python will expect them to be in the same folder. If you refer to `images/background.png` instead, python will expect there to be a folder called `images` in the same directory as `game.py`, and a file called `background.png` inside that. And so on. In other words, **images and filepaths are relative to the directory the file using them is in.**

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you have a **pygame** folder and **inside** that lies those executables that fires up your `pygame instance`, so for that you need to load that image also.

> pygame/
>
> -----------mygame.py

Now your `pygame instance` searches for the **image** which can have either relative or absolute pathnames.

*In the same directory* quintessentially means the folder/directory where your executable instance is running (eg mygame.py etc), so you have to copy-paste your **image** to that directory in layman terms and run the `mygame.py` again.

Directory structure updates to:

> pygame/
>
> -----------mygame.py
>
> -----------background.jpg